# mysql "group by" fields orders

Tags: mysql

I have a question about using "group by" in mysql: group order whether to affect the efficiency of query.

```
1.SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `er_ct`, `appve`  FROM TBL_547 WHERE UAEWA_ts >= 1417276800 AND UAEWA_ts <= 1417449540 GROUP BY `appve`, `er_ct` ORDER BY `c79fd348-cc8e-41f2-ae93-0b2b2cde8a31`  DESC  limit  5;
2.SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `er_ct`, `appve`  FROM TBL_547 WHERE UAEWA_ts >= 1417276800 AND UAEWA_ts <= 1417449540 GROUP BY  `er_ct`,`appve` ORDER BY `c79fd348-cc8e-41f2-ae93-0b2b2cde8a31`  DESC  limit  5;
```

The difference betwen two sentence is "GROUP BY `appve`, `er_ct` " and " GROUP BY  `er_ct`,`appve`".There is no index(combined index) on appve and er_ct. The value of "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT er_ct) FROM TBL_547" is 7000. The value of "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT appve) FROM TBL_547" is 3.

here is the screenshot.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AeQy2.png

the structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgAy.png

thanks.

Comment: You need an index on `UAEWA_ts`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i have index on UAEWA_ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating index on column with group by will not boost your results. When you perform a query, the SQL statement first gets compiled into a tree of relational algebra operations. These operations each take one or more tables as input and produce another table as output. Then using the output table SQL engine is applying any other operations:
- agregation - group by
- sorting

So you can boost your query mostly by:
- creating smart queries, like on only indexed columns.
- asuring your result set is not huge, and not accesssing all joined tble columns, like Select * is a total overkill on production

I would also recommend [SQL Tuning](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-596-00573-3) as an lecture. I hope my answer will help.

First think that  pops in my mind is size of distinct results in both columns, you mentioned 3 and 7k, that would be the main factor I assume.
When query optimizer (they are changing all the time) will see that first group column is small, it will just go with the flow, but if he sees that the first column is large (7k distinct results) he could go with building up an index on it. That operation on a large column could be slow, thats why you have two different times for both queries.

Comment: thanks...but can  you explain why it perform such a huge difference from the pciture. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AeQy2.png

Comment: Could you also run an explain statement on your queries, that would give us more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html :)

Comment: I have run two explain at the bottom of the picture. Here is the structure of the table: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgAy.png

Comment: Thanks will try to find the bug:) I am not a rocket scientist, so be patient:)

Comment: Thanks, here is some more information: The value of "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT er_ct) FROM TBL_547" is 7000. The value of "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT appve) FROM TBL_547" is 3.
I think they are related.

Comment: I think I had found your problem, look in my post.

Comment: Thanks :).But do you konw how to prevent query optimizer to build index? On the other hand, I think 10s is enough to build index on 7k data. It is unbeliveable to take 40s to build index on 7k data.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not on this level yet:) I don't know if it is possible. From my experience you should not disable it, bacause without index  SQL Engine would have to perform operations on not indexed columns, and that would also be slow, so I assume there is litte or no benefin to it. Bes solution would be to build good queries:) Here you know what column is larger and that will give you a hint.